# WPF Perfomance issues when Tablet PC Input Service is running

Tags: wpf, performance

When we deploy our WPF (.Net 4.0) application in Windows 7 Tablets or Windows 7 Laptops with TouchScreen where the Tablet PC Input Service is running, all of our ComboBoxes and TextBoxes are very sluggish. When we stop this service, everything works fine.
I have found a couple of places where this was mentioned [before](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsaccessibilityandautomation/thread/6c4465e2-207c-4277-a67f-e0f55eff0110) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/02/16/wpf-4-and-visual-studio-2010-ui-automation-performance-on-tablets-touch-enabled-machines.aspx). I've also tried to build our application in .Net 4.5 and also installing on the machines with the problem the .Net 4.5 Framework with no results. On the desktops and on the tablets with Windows XP, the application run fine. Does anybody else experience the same problem? and if yes, how do you resolve it?